# Update value in Parse.com

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to update a value in my Parse.com table named: "currentUploaded".

This is my query from Parse.com code:
http://pastebin.com/Jr0EcJuy

Parse.com “currentUploads” class: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8tND.png

This is the button i want to do the update value(as it is now, it create a new row in another class, but i just want to increase the "reportedCount" of the selected item instead:

```
@IBAction func reportContentAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.collectionView)
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(buttonPosition)
        ////
        println(indexPath?.item)
        ////
        let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath!.item]

        var alertMessage = NSString(format:"*User: %@\r *Text: %@\r *Created at %@", post.username, post.text, post.CreatedAt)

        var reportAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Report Content", message:alertMessage as String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        reportAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            println("Handle Report Logic here")

            var currentUploads = PFObject(className: "banned")
            currentUploads["username"] = post.username
            currentUploads["imageText"] = post.text
            currentUploads["imageFile"] = post.image
            currentUploads["identifierForVendor"] = post.deviceID
            currentUploads["flaggedBy"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
            currentUploads["flaggedByUUID"] = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
            currentUploads.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    //**Success saving, now save image.**//
                    currentUploads.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil{
                            // Take user home
                            print("Data uploaded")
                            // Show UIAlertView
                            let alert = UIAlertView()
                            alert.title = "Message"
                            alert.message = "You report has been sent. Thank you for your support."
                            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Close")
                            alert.show()

                        }
                        else{
                            print(error)
                        }
                    })
                }
                else{
                    print(error)
                }
            })
        }))

        reportAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            println("Handle Cancel Logic here")
        }))

        presentViewController(reportAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I have also tried using this code when the user click yes on the popup, but it doesn't work:

```
reportAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            println("Handle Report Logic here")

            var query = PFQuery(className: "currentUploads")
            query.whereKey("imageFile", equalTo: post.image)
            query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (myObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (error != nil){
                    println(error)
                    //
                }
                else{
                    query.setValue("1", forKey: "reportedCount")
                }
            }
        }))
```

Please, can someone show me how it should be correct? Have been struggling on this for many many hours now..

Answer (score 2):

a small example

```
   let someQuery = PFQuery(className: "banned")
   someQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(someclass.objectId) {
        (updatedObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if let updatedObject = updatedObject {
            updatedObject["NameOfTheFieldYouWantToChange"] = newValue
            updatedObject.saveInBackground()
        }

    }
```

someclass.objectId — it's just an objectId value for the raw you want to update. I don't know where you are storing it.

"NameOfTheFieldYouWantToChange" — name of the field you want to change :)

newValue — new value for this field.

P.S. Also it seems that you are trying to put your Parse code to your ViewController class. Compiler won't care so it will work, but it's not a good practice. It would be much more simpler for you to put all these database operations to different class (MVC pattern).

Comment: I dont know how i would do the different class thingy? You mean subclassing or something? I dont know how to do that from my method.

Comment: I didn't understand the some class.objectid either, what to put there?

Comment: you want to change some row (object) in your table. this row has objectId. to use this objectId is the simplest way to tell table what exactly object you want to change.

Comment: about MVC pattern — you can begin with https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html